# Python: как запустить input() параллельно с print()?

Tags: python

`input()` в python полностью стопит весь код до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет данные. Можно ли как-то запустить `input()` параллельно вместе с `print()`? Пишу программу чата между двумя устройствами в локальной сети и нужно, чтобы пользователь мог одновременно читать сообщения (`print()`) и в любой момент отправлять свои так, чтобы программа не замораживалась пока он вводит данные.

На данный момент ввод реализован в отдельном окне :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python поддерживает различные формы конкурентности (asyncio,threading,multiprocessing):
https://habr.com/ru/post/421625/

С asyncio и threading память "потоков" общая, как вам видимо и надо.

Различия в синтаксисе и в соотношении с потоками ОС.

Answer (score 0):

То что вы описали происходит из-за [GIL](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).

> Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) — это способ синхронизации потоков, который используется в некоторых интерпретируемых языках программирования, например в Python и Ruby.

Для реализации чата стоит взять [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). [Вопрос по реализации простого чата в английской версии StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060346/creating-a-simple-chat-application-in-python-sockets).

В этом случае необходимо создать сервер и отдельный клиент, таким образом через sockets в локальной сети вы сможете передавать и получать информацию на всех клиентах одновременно.

[Статья о socket на Хабре](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/149077/)

Comment: Это происходит не из-за GIL, у человека просто синхронный код.

Comment: Соглашусь, видимо не доглядел поздней ночью. В данном конкретном вопросе действительно речь про синхронность кода.